# Show codebehinde in aspx

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hi i just open new page in VS and added one simple line, question why date time isn't showing? There is just blak page.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <%# DateTime.Now.ToString() %>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Cultivate good coding habits by setting the date in your code-behind and applying it to a label. Keep display and logic separate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`<%# ... %>` is [data-binding syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bda9bbfx%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), which basically means that the expression will not be evaluated until `DataBind()` is called. Since you do not call `DataBind()`, nothing gets printed.

The syntax for evaluating the expression immediately would be:

```
<%= DateTime.Now.ToString() %>
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use:

```
<% Response.write(DateTime.Now.ToString()) %>
```

`<%=` is equivalent to Response.Write so you can use `<%=` too.

```
 <%= DateTime.Now.ToString() %>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the **equals** sign for a shorter notation:

```
<% = DateTime.Now.ToString() %>
```